# $\mbox{div}(A(x) \nabla u) = 0$ in $B_1 $ with $A(x) \in C^{\gamma}\Rightarrow u \in C^{\gamma}_{Loc}?$

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

What is the regularity of solutions of
\begin{equation}
\mbox{div}(A(x) \nabla u) = 0\ \mbox{in}\ B_1
\end{equation}
in the weak sense (distributional sense) where the matrix $A(x)$ is Hölder continuous, this is, $A(x) \in C^{0, \gamma}(B_1)$ and $B_1$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
\begin{equation}
\lambda |\xi|^{2} \le \langle A(x)\xi , \xi \rangle \le |\xi|^{2} \quad \forall  x,\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n}.
\end{equation} 
I know by De digiorge that if $A(x)$ is only a measurable matrix, then $u \in C^{\alpha}(B_{1/2})$ for a specific $\alpha \in (0,1)$.  I want to know if the hypothesis $ A(x) \in C^{\gamma}$ implies in a regularity $u \in C^{\gamma}(B_{1/2})$. If possible I'd like to know some reference that comproves the assertion.

Comment: I've edited the title and body to remove `\quad`s. A simple `\` should suffice when you need a space; forcing `\quad` in there breaks the typesetting for many people.

Answer (score 1):

It even implies $u\in C^{1,\gamma}$ (which is the natural degree of regularity, given that $A$ and $\nabla u$ participate in the equation in a similar way). This is Theorem 8.22 in Gilbarg-Trudinger, page 210. They merely sketch the proof, saying that it's similar to the Schauder approach to non-divergence equations with Hölder coefficients.